# MySQL query using special characters

Tags: php, mysql

Every time I insert data using an SQL query I get an error. I suspect it's because of the apostrophes in the `$post` value.

The SQL query is:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO posts (id_str, post, time, rt) VALUES ('$id_str','$post', '$time', '$rt')";
```

but my `$post` value is

```
$post = "My test posts are not as 'inconsistent' as before";
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3):

[mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) should do the escape for you.

Comment: Exactly. And always try to look into security issues before accepting input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

The most basic solution is to `mysql_real_escape_string()`.